# setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) doesn't work

Tags: java, android

my first question here!

I'm building two very common buttons: one to set text to ITALIC and one to set text to BOLD. When both are pressed the text must be BOLD_ITALIC.

The italic button works perfectly, but the BOLD button doesn't work when the text is ITALIC and I really don't know why.

```
public void Bold(View view) {

    ScrollTextView mScrollTextView = (ScrollTextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_text_main);
    if(mScrollTextView.getTypeface()!=null){

        if(mScrollTextView.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.ITALIC){
            mScrollTextView.setText("if italic, then change to bold_italico");
            mScrollTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        }
        if(mScrollTextView.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC){

            //mScrollTextView.setText("boudi italico!");

            mScrollTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
        }
        else if(!mScrollTextView.getTypeface().isBold()){

            mScrollTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        } else {
            mScrollTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `else` before the second `if`.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> public void setTypeface (Typeface tf)
>
> Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed. Note that not all Typeface families actually have bold and italic variants, so you may need to use setTypeface(Typeface, int) to get the appearance that you actually want.

And

> public void setTypeface (Typeface tf, int style)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed, and turns on the fake bold and italic bits in the Paint if the Typeface that you provided does not have all the bits in the style that you specified.